# Review GitHub own activity for extended period

Tags: github

I would like to review my GitHub activities for the past 12 months. On my public profile I can see as much as one month only. I can go to an individual repository and review all the commits for any period of time, of course, but this becomes unfeasible when I have to interleave data from dozens of repositories.

Is there an advanced query or page that allows me to see or download this aggregated data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like GitHub does not allow viewing contribution data for more than a Month by default but if you use it's apis you can build something that can keep track of your contribution for how ever long you want it to.

Here's where GitHub talks about contribution.
https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile-page/